# finding a dynamic element using telerik framework

Tags: telerik, telerik-test-studio

I am very new to the telerik framework i have a que with finding dynamic elements.For example lets consider a  where the content keeps changing.In selenium i will find the elements using the following code

```
IWebElement location = Browser.FindElement(By.Id("dynamic-ul")).FindElement(By.TagName("ul"));
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> Totalli = location.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));
Totalli.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FindElement(By.ClassName("selectable")).Text == Test).Click;
```

what i want to know is it possible to do the same in telerik test studio. After taking the root element i am not able to select the child element for example

```
var location = myManager.ActiveBrowser.Find.ById("dynamic-ul").Find.ByTagName("ul");
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Find.ByExpression as shown below:

```
var location = Manager.ActiveBrowser.Find.ByExpression("tagname=ul,id=dynamic-ul");
```

Answer (score -1):

If only some numbers are chaging in you element ID
ex: mybutton_12, mybutton_24 you can use properties like Element name
Starts with
ends with
or using a reguler exresssion

use this link [handle Dynamic IDS](http://kazztr.blogspot.com/2017/01/handling-dynamic-ids-from-telerik.html)

Comment: this is not the answer to the question. you just promoting your blog.